# Password protected wall

Tags: passwords, one-time-password, protection

I'm currently building a website where you have an account and can do "dangerous" things with it. I want to password-protect these things, so the user has to type their password, if they want to continue.
I couldn't find any ressources on this, so I came up with this idea.

My method works this way:

1. User navigates to dangerous action
2. The server redirects the user to the password prompt website
3. The user types the password
4. The server checks if the typed in password matches the currently logged in user
5. If check was successfull, the server redirects the user to the action with a uniquely created token associated to the user as a GET parameter
6. The dangerous actions checks if the token matches to the user
7. If match, the server will continue as normal

My question: Is this secure?

I think this is secure because I will probably make the token like 511 chars long and bruteforcing it would be very unlikely and I couldn't find any other security holes in this.

Comment: This is basically what GitHub does when you do something like deleting a repository, no?

Comment: I don't know but I guess when Github does this, it must be secure?

Comment: @Myzel394 Do avoid [argument from authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority)

Comment: If server stores the user ID the token was given to and invalidates/deletes the token after The action was performed, you should be good imho. The first thing would avoid token theft and the second one would prevent reusing previous tokens after user lost its privileges

Comment: @bradbury9 Why is it better to avoid arguments from authority? When I know that Github has strong protection and hasn't had much data leaks in the past, it must be, because their security is good.

Comment: You get the risk of a false sense of security. It is better to analyze the scenario and attack vectors regardless of who implemented it.

Comment: @bradbury9 Yes that's actually true. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: @bradbury9 Until fairly recently, many people would have been as happy to say "_I know Equifax has strong protection..._".

Answer (score 2):

**Homebrewed security is dangerous**

The thing you are describing already well developed with a multitude of publicly audited libraries and tools available for almost every web platform. A great place to start would be with `oauth2`. Even a service like `auth0` might work, which would essentially be the "password server".

The danger of doing this yourself is that the concept of token-based authentication has a lot of subtle pitfalls that have already been analyzed, but you are likely to make (at least) one of several obvious mistakes.

Comment: I couldn't find any ressources, but thank you that you gave me some hints! I know self-made security is not good but everything started somewhere, maybe someone will find a better security at home someday?